# scale_fill_manual not working after sorting

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, colors, conditional-operator

I have the following code. I want to color the USA value in red. But it keeps coloring the place where the USA would've been if I hadn't reordered it. Why? I've tried changing countries into factors, to no avail.

```
# Sort the data frame by 'val' in ascending order
df <- df[order(df$val), ]

# plot 
p <- ggplot(data = df, 
            aes(x = reorder(country, val), 
                                      y = val, 
                                      fill = country)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = 
                      ifelse(density_df$country == "USA", "red", "darkblue")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Setting your colors using an `ifelse` in `scale_fill_manual` is error prone and I would not recommend to do so. Instead map your condition on the fill aes e.g. do `fill = country == "USA"` and use `scale_fill_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "red", "FALSE" = "darkblue"))`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Answer (score 0):

@stefan is right - you will likely get unexpected results by deviating from the usual syntax in `ggplot`.

What I think you want to do is [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-highlight-a-bar-in-barplot-in-r/#).

In this example, they created a dummy variable that aligns with your version of "USA", ie., the highlighted level.  Then they used a call to `fill =` to create the color difference, which are mapped to the dummy variable.  In other words, you would use `fill =` on the dummy variable (not `country`) and specify the colors in `scale_fill_manual` that correspond to the colors you want.

You can put this dummy variable and even the colors directly into your data frame if you'd like.

It is a bit non-intuitive the first few times you see it, but it may help you to think of `ggplot` arguments as their own set of data elements.  Many of those come from your data frame but some tricks require you to set up their own variables.